# Let α ∈ ℝ and Tα = { (n,α): n ∈ ℕ }

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let α ∈ ℝ and Tα = { (n,α): n ∈ ℕ }

Part 1 Determine the set union Ti for i∈ℝ

Part 2 Determine the set intersection Ti for i∈ℝ

I need some help figuring it out because I only got part of part 1 correct but I completely messed up the second part on the test.  I'd like to know the answer so I can see how it actually needs to be done.  Thank you!

Comment: How are a and α related?

Comment: I apologize, I meant to put α instead of a.  It is edited now.

Comment: Please use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference It'll make your question much nicer to read.